# How can users move emails between exchange mailboxes without being able to read the emails in the destination mailbox?

Tags: email, exchange-server, user-permissions

Our sales process uses a 'sales' mailbox with a number of sub folders for each stage of the sales cycle. As emails move through the cycle they are moved from one sub-folder to the next. No internal emails about an opportunity are allowed (either To, Cc or BCC) as discussion takes place on chatter

On occasion a salesperson needs to move an email into a manager's email inbox, but they don't have access to the mailbox.

How can we set up permissions for the salesperson so that they are able to drag and drop the email into a mailbox, but so they don't have visibility of the emails or folder structure inside.

We're using Outlook 2013 and office 365 (and thus a Microsoft hosted exchange server).

A good answer for this question would either describe the permissions required and how to achieve the desired outcome OR suggest workarounds

At present its not practical for us to move to a helpdesk solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with this Exchange is based partly on NTFS permissions and you cannot be given Modify permissions without being given read permissions.

You could encrypt the contents of the email before moving it into Sales and then have the application that moves the emails around can decrypt it when sending it to the manager or displaying it within the application.